# SQLite in 10 UWP App Assertion Error (p->iForeGuard==(int)FOREGUARD);

Tags: c#, c++, sqlite

I have a Windows 10 Store app that is using SQLite and the SQLite.Net-PCL wrapper.  SQLite is at version 3.9.2.  All references are included (i.e SQLite for Universal App Platform, Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps, etc)

I am sporadically getting a C++ exception for Assertion Failed at assert( p->iForeGuard==(int)FOREGUARD );

There seems to be little information on this error.  I understand that it is an assertion error (obviously :)) that is coming from the SQLite dll.  I found a similar bug on another github project (https://github.com/mbrit/sqlite-metrostyle/issues/2) but this has no resolution either.  Below is how I am creating my SQLite connection

```
private SQLiteConnection Connection
        => new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DBPath,
            SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);
```

I have played around with the open flags to no avail. I have multiple threads that may call SQLite and from what I can gather from the docs using FullMutex and SharedCache should allow for this (Please correct me if I am wrong)

I have since created a wrapper class to ensure that the connection was closed immediately since I read in a discussion that this may be the cause of the error.  Here is an example of one of my wrapper methods

```
public T FirstOrDefault<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
{
    using (var conn = Connection)
    {
        var result = conn.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        //Explicitly close the connection rather then wait for the dispose to do it
        conn.Close();
        return result;
    }            
}
```

This initially appeared to resolve the issue, but is has reared it's ugly head again.  I am at a loss at this point.  I have also tried using the SQLite.Net.Asyn-PCL library and that was no different as I would expect.

Any help or insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to get this issue resolved.  Apparently in contradiction to how it was described as what should be done, a single connection to the database needs to be used.  I was able to fix it by using a single SQLiteConnectionWithLock and using the Connection.Lock() when accessing the database.

Here is what I ended up using

```
private SQLiteConnectionWithLock _connection;

private SQLiteConnectionWithLock Connection
    =>
        _connection ??
        (_connection = new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(),
            new SQLiteConnectionString(App.DBPath, false,
                openFlags:
                    SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex |
                    SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache)));
```

Then when accessing the db used the connection lock

```
public int Count<T>() where T : class
{
    using (Connection.Lock())
    {
        var result = Connection.Table<T>().Count();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. I had the same issue in my Windows 10 UAP app, though all i was doing was a bunch of reads so I didn't see anything wrong with having multiple connections but perhaps I had too many or opened them too quickly.. anyways it's working using your code!